# Kubernetes containers running, but localhost returns 404 when trying to access the services

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to learn to deploy to kubernetes from the microsoft learning page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-deploy-microservices-kubernetes/4-exercise-deploy-to-kubernetes

after i run the services, it tells me that localhost must now point to my application.
but http://localhost returns error 404

'kubectl get pods' returns

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pizzabackend-7f55dbc6fc-qm4rg    1/1     Running   0          29m
pizzafrontend-7484c45b97-g4vk4   1/1     Running   0          10m
```

so i think my pods are running fine.

any idea what I'm missing here? or why localhost cannot access the services?

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5pG8.png)

Comment: can you do kubectl port-forward  pizzafrontend-7484c45b97-g4vk4 8080:80 and then browse to http://localhost:8080 ? the problem may be that your kubernetes cluster can get access on the 80 port.

Comment: thanks a lot! this solves my issue. Will read up on port forwarding

Comment: is the reason for this, that, somehow, port 80 wasn't accessible?

Comment: i think it is a default rule on Windows firewall but not sure.
happy to know it did solve your problem.
i'll add it as an answer.

Comment: That microsoft docs doesn't tell about kubectl port-forward - though for sure, you have to do this, if you want to test without setting up an Ingress. Then again, microsoft docs being inaccurate isn't really surprising ... Kubernetes has their own docs, which is usually perfect. It's not that port is blocked: the yaml you applied did create a LoadBalancer service listening on port 80. If your cluster has LoadBalancer support (which is not a given), then you should connect to your LB address, on port 80. For sure, localhost won''t work unless you port-forward directly into your pod.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using port forward on your frontend app and change the access port from the client to 8080 or something other then 80.
i will not be surprised if that port is blocked by windows or that you already run something on that exact port in another application.