# Unable to browse DotNet Core Microservices deployed on Docker Kubernetes locally

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, microservices

I am following this article [Deploy a microservice container to Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/dotnet-deploy-microservices-kubernetes/4-exercise-deploy-to-kubernetes) which is about deploying Dot Net Core backend and frontend microservices to Docker Desktop Kubernetes.  But unable to
browse to http://localhost to see both microservices running. I see below error page:

[image]

I don't see any error while deploying the backend and frontend service:
[image]

My *backend-deploy.yml* and *frontend-deploy.yml* is exactly same as given in the tutorial just [YOUR DOCKER USER NAME] placeholder replaced with my docker hub user name.
But when I visit http://localhost to see both microservices running, I see 404 error page. Please explain what's wrong that I am doing.

When I run `kubectl get services` I get this:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there's a `/` endpoint?

Comment: @doneforaiur yes, there is. I found this answer so checking it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526065/kubernetes-containers-running-but-localhost-returns-404-when-trying-to-access-t?rq=2 
Not sure if it will work. 
Yes it works. `kubectl port-forward pizzafrontend-598c88564-tkqz9 8080:80` command fixed my issue.

Comment: Since your issue is resolved. can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of community.